# Javascript this in global context doesn't work, or seems like console.log works but using ref doesn't work

Tags: javascript, this

So I am wondering the difference between the two calls in below code: 
My understanding is once I get ref to function using user.credential.getID , I should be able to execute it and which seems to work fine in console.log(user.credentials.getID());// it works

```js
const user = {
  id: 551,
  name: 'Tom',
  getID() {
    return this.id;
  },

  credentials: {
    id: 120,
    name: 'Jack',
    getID() {
      return this.id;
    }
  }

}
var getId = user.credentials.getId;
console.log(getId); // undefined why?
console.log(user.credentials.getID()); // it works
```

Comment: `getId` and `getID` are not the same.

Comment: This should have been closed as a duplicate. The typo could be fixed and it would still fail. This is a duplicate of one of the fundamental "How does 'this' work?" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one rule to keep in mind, `this` takes its value from where the function has been called. If you call a function from an object, for example `obj.func()`, `this` will be `obj`. If you call it from nowhere, for example `func()`, `this` will be `undefined` or `window`, depending on whether you're in `strict mode` or not.

Comment: but line console.log(getId); , shouldn't print [function : getID], instead of undefined

Comment: It's case sensitive, you mistyped it

Comment: Thanks, next time more caution and good questions will be posted. you people are awesome.